# invested value + profit (-loss) =?

Tags: stocks, terminology

What is the financial name **which a broker would give** to the following returns:

- invested capital = 1000
- profit = 2%
- **currentValue1** = 1000*1.02 = 1020 $
- **currentValue2** = 100%+2% = 102%

**MarketValue** is not the right name for currentValue1, if the position is already closed.

What does `currentValue1` and `currentValue2` stand for? Are these the `gross return`, the `cash flow` or have the two other names (common in financial world)?

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could refer to the above; it will depend on the context of how you are talking about it. These are not technical enough definitions that there is only one right way to say it.

Comment: If you can provide further details on how these terms will be used (is this a user guide for software, or a finance textbook, or are you trying to understand the terms 'gross return' and 'cash flow' and trying to check if these match it?), it might make this answerable, but as-is it is quite vague.

Comment: I have a gain and add it to my base value. Which names will a broker give to these values? Gross profit? Or something else? **Net change** is wrong because it's `base value + net change` (for relative value). And  **market value** (for absolute value) is also not right if I have no position.

Comment: In what context is the broker referring to it? Is this on an annual statement showing year over year return? Is it a status page showing current asset values? There are lots of ways to refer to these. "market value", which you rejected as an answer below, could be correct, especially if it totals value of open positions + available cash.

Comment: Yes, it's a status page showing current asset values? Which names for the given two values would be appropriate for this? MarketValue is not correct, if I have no position opened. I think `return capital` is the most appropriate word for `currentValue1`.

Comment: Your edit attempts to clarify but it has an inherent flaw - if you have closed the position, and don't want to refer to it as market value, doesn't that mean the number $1040 is irrelevant? You could call it the 'market value at the time of sale', or 'sale price' or something similar, but again, these aren't very technical terms, how to say it will depend still on context. You say "how would a broker say it", but what is the kind of statement the broker trying to say? Is the broker trying to tell you what your position *used to be*, or *currently is*, or what is the success of their strategy?

Comment: Total capital could be correct, if it was adding your cash + closed positions, but in that case 'market value' could also be correct. The market value of a bank account with $1,040 in cash is $1,040. "Return capital" doesn't really sound right to me, but a portion of your audience might understand it.

Comment: yes, I think **market value** is the most appropriate (even if a position is closed, because that's the current market value (also in terms of the current value represented by a currency). For currentValue2, I don't know. Maybe marketValuePercent.

Comment: yes, mark to market is also a good fit. However, for the second value: it is not only the 2%, but the 102%. I find to call it "working percents", I cannot find a better name for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1,000 is investment or cost basis

If the position is still open, $20 is the current gain which is 2% (ROI) and the current or market value would be $1,020.

If the position is closed, it would be called the  final value or proceeds from sale.

There are a variety of other interchangeable financial terms to describe the above (profit, gain, yield, return, etc.).

My guess is that this is from a textbook because terms like `currentValue1` and `currentValue2` tend to come from the academic world.

Answer (score 3):

- CurrentValue1 stands for MarketValue
- CurrentValue2 stands for RelativeChange

You don't realize profit/loss, unless you sell the stock. So, there is no cash flow here.

Comment: `MarketValue` seems appropriate, but `NetChange` is wrong. Because the `NetChange` is 2%. But I ask for the name of "102%".

Comment: @nimo23, agree with you. I was about to delete my answer as Netchange is not right. I will update with right term.

Comment: I don't think that `MarketValue` is the right term for this. What if I already exit the position. There is not marketValue here. Only `base value + gain`.

Comment: @nimo23 "What if I already exit the position" then that context changes the answer. Most finance terminology is only semi-technical. By that I mean - it is not always very precise. How you refer to something will differ depending on the context. The way you have asked the question, it is difficult to come up with a single 'correct' answer that will apply in all situations, because those situations will change the common parlance.